# Bootstrap Pills issue

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 pills to show form in different parts, It work's fine when I only put some text for all tabs but when I put some html form code in home tab, that form is getting printed in all tabs:

I want to put separate data for each tab pill. For Example: Different forms for each tab.

My Code:

```
     <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link active" data-target="#home-pills" aria-controls="home-pills" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Patient Details</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link" data-target="#profile-pills" aria-controls="profile-pills" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Pre OP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link" data-target="#messages-pills" aria-controls="messages-pills" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Intra</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link" data-target="#settings-pills" aria-controls="settings-pills" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Post OP</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane in active" id="home-pills">
                <form>
                    <form action='insert.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Patient ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="patient_id" class="form-control boxed" placeholder="Enter Patient ID">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Date Of Surgery</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control boxed" name="date_of_surgery">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
      
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-pills">
                <h4>Profile Tab</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages-pills">
                <h4>Messages Tab</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings-pills">
                <h4>Settings Tab</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-block -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-xl-12 -->
<script>
    // Select all tabs
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function(){
  $(this).tab('show');
})
</script>
```

It's printing Patient (Home Tab) form for all the tabs.
Can Anyone help?

Comment: Hello. What's your problem? Do you want to display the form in only one tab?

Comment: @s-kuznetsov I want to put separate data for each tab pill. For Example: Different forms for each tab.